# Javascript clear timeout on mousemove

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, timeout

I have created an animated menu that opens when the users cursor is placed within 20px of the right hand side of their screen. I want to prevent the menu opening if the users cursor moves out of this region within 2 seconds but I'm struggling with the Javascript timeouts. My code looks like this so far:

HTML

Javascript
        // Timer variable
        var timer;

```
    function openToolbar()
    {               
        // Only execute for desktop
        $('.no-touch').on('mousemove',function(event) {

            // Toolbar and Window width
            var tableToolbar = $('.ac-table-toolbar'),
                winWidth = $(window).width();

            // If cursor enters right hand side of the screen start the timer
            // and execute after 2 seconds                  
            if(event.pageX > (winWidth - 20)) {

                // Timeout
                timer = setTimeout(function()
                {
                    // Add active class to toobar and css transition will animate it
                    // to open position
                    tableToolbar.addClass('active').removeClass('notActive');
                }, 2000);
            }

            // If mouse pointer leaves right hand side of the screen and
            // still has notActive class cancel the timeout to prevent
            // the toolbar from opening
            if(event.pageX < (winWidth - 20) && tableToolbar.hasClass('notActive'))
            {
                clearTimeout(timer);
            }

            // Toolbar has active class so we know its visible
            if(tableToolbar.hasClass('active') && event.pageX < (winWidth - 220))
            {
                // Clear timeout (if needed?)
                clearTimeout(timer);

                // Remove active class and css transition will return it to docked position
                tableToolbar.removeClass('active').addClass('notActive');
            }                   
        });
    }
```

The animation is handled with CSS transitions that are triggered by the active notActive classes.

Please can anyone point me in the right direction. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Offtopic slightly, but you don't need to re-define tableToolbar and winWidth every time the mouse moves, so I suggest moving the `var tableToolbar = $('.ac-table-toolbar'), winWidth = $(window).width();` outside `mousemove` event callback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Too complex for this task. Big amount of `mousemove` events will slow down your page. Try to use another approach:

HTML:

```
<div id='rightActivateZone'></div>
```

CSS:

```
#rightActivateZone {
    background-color: red; // change to transparent for your purpose
    height: 100%;
    width: 20px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;    
}
```

JS:

```
var timer;
$('#rightActivateZone').on('mouseenter', function() {
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
        alert('fire!'); // your code to show menu is here              
    }, 2000);
});
$('#rightActivateZone').on('mouseleave', function() {
    clearTimeout(timer);
});
```

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Q2LUA/1/)

Answer (score 1):

I agree with finelords answer.  That is the best approach but to answer your question

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/EZJv6/

We had to do a check on the timer being in existence aswell, see comments below.

JS:

```
var timer = null;

function openToolbar() {
    // Moved these out of event to prevent re-processing.
    // Toolbar and Window width
    var tableToolbar = $('.ac-table-toolbar'),
        winWidth = $(window).width();
    // Only execute for desktop
    $('.no-touch').on('mousemove', function (event) {
        // If cursor enters right hand side of the screen start the timer
        // and execute after 2 seconds

        // here you are setting a timer on every mousemove, even the ones when the cursor is over the active bar so we need to fix by checking if
        if (event.pageX > (winWidth - 20) && tableToolbar.hasClass('notActive') && timer == null) {
            // Timeout
            console.log('setting timeout');
            timer = setTimeout(function () {
                // Add active class to toobar and css transition will animate it to open position
                tableToolbar.addClass('active').removeClass('notActive');
            }, 500);
        }
        // If mouse pointer leaves right hand side of the screen and
        // still has notActive class cancel the timeout to prevent
        // the toolbar from opening
        if (event.pageX < (winWidth - 20) && tableToolbar.hasClass('notActive') && timer != null) {
            clearTimeout(timer);
            timer = null;
            console.log('cancelling timeout 1');
        }
        // Toolbar has active class so we know its visible
        if (tableToolbar.hasClass('active') && event.pageX < (winWidth - 20)) {
            // Clear timeout (if needed?)
            clearTimeout(timer);
            timer = null;
            console.log('cancelling timeout 2');
            // Remove active class and css transition will return it to docked position
            tableToolbar.removeClass('active').addClass('notActive');
        }
    });
}

openToolbar();
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than clearing the time out, perhaps let it run, but keep track of the latest mouse position

```
var currentX;    

function openToolbar()
{               
    // Only execute for desktop
    $('.no-touch').on('mousemove',function(event) {

        currentX = event.pageX;

        // Toolbar and Window width
        var tableToolbar = $('.ac-table-toolbar'),
            winWidth = $(window).width();

        // If cursor enters right hand side of the screen start the timer
        // and execute after 2 seconds                  
        if(currentX > (winWidth - 20)) {

            // Timeout
            timer = setTimeout(function()
            {
                // check the mouse position after the timeout
                if(currentX > (winWidth - 20)) {
                    // Add active class to toobar and css transition will animate it
                    // to open position
                    tableToolbar.addClass('active').removeClass('notActive');
                }
            }, 2000);
        }

        // Toolbar has active class so we know its visible
        if(tableToolbar.hasClass('active') && currentX < (winWidth - 220))
        {
            // Remove active class and css transition will return it to docked position
            tableToolbar.removeClass('active').addClass('notActive');
        }                   
    });
}
```